# What type of angle is $3+ \frac{1}{6}$ of a complete rotation?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Angle less than $90$ deg is acute, angle greater than $90$ and less than $180$ is obtuse and angle greater than $180$ deg is reflex. Now, what if an angle is a $3+\frac{1}{6}$ of a complete rotation? After $3$ complete rotations, the remaining angle is $\large{360 \times \frac{1}{6} = 60}$ deg i.e. final angle between the two lines of the angle is $60$ deg. But this angle is after $3$ complete rotations? So, is this a reflex angle? OR an acute angle?

I am sure missing something simple. Your enlightenment will be a great help. Thanks in advance.
--Adnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definitions are:

$\alpha$ is  an **acute** angle if $0°<\alpha<90°$

$\alpha$ is  an **obtuse** angle if $90°<\alpha<180°$

$\alpha$ is  a **reflex** angle if $180°<\alpha<360°$

So your angle $\theta=(3+\frac{1}{6})\times 360°$ does not fit any (usual) definition. Obviously the residual angle $\theta-3\times 360°$ is acute.

Comment: While searching for answers, I just came across this: [http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55067.html](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55067.html). It says, it is an acute _reference_ angle -- well not exactly an acute angle but a sort of acute angle anyway, so to say?

Comment: I don't know this nomenclature. Anyway, in your reference I see that $\theta$: **had** an acute "reference angle"*, (that in this case is $60°$) not that it **is** an acute reference angle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a reflex angle, but it is certainly not acute.  Acute angles are only between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.  The measure of the angle in question is $3\cdot 360^\circ +60^\circ=1140^\circ$.